# Create zip file of logging file using python module logging

Tags: python-2.7, logging

I want to create a zip file of logging file. I have created logging file using python module logging and RotatingFileHandler.

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler


 # create a logging format
    log_formatter = logging.Formatter('Date: %(asctime)s - %(message)s')
    logFile = scheduler_name + "_"+ scheduler_id+".log"

    # create a file handler
    myhandler = RotatingFileHandler(logFile, mode='a', maxBytes=5*1024*1024, 
                                     backupCount=2, encoding=None, delay=0)
    myhandler.setFormatter(log_formatter)
    myhandler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    # add the handlers to the logger
    app_log = logging.getLogger()
    app_log.addHandler(myhandler)
```

Using that I have created a logging file and I want to create zip file using logging module inbuilt functionality

Answer (score 0):

I didnt try, but possibly it should be like this. Take care of dst_file_name to generate dynamically just like your 'logFile'

```
import commands
myhandler.doRollover()
for i in range(self.backupCount, 0, -1):
    dst_file_name='myzip.zip'
    src_file_name=scheduler_name + "_"+i+".log"
    cmd = "zip %s %s" %(dst_file_name, src_file_name)
    commands.getoutput(cmd)
```

enter code here

Comment: I want to create using logging inbuilt functionality. so it can't work for me.

Comment: inherit your code...class mylog(RotatingFileHandler): and in that class, override doRollover() with the above code.